# Serializing Guava's ImmutableTable

Tags: java, serialization, guava

I am using the version 17.0 of **Guava**, especially the new collection types. While trying to write an `ImmutableTable` through a `Socket`, I realized that the class and its concrete implementations do not seem to be serializable.

However, the two following tickets seem to indicate that the developers are aware of the issue:

- [Issue 1264](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1264)
- [Issue 1562](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1562)

Do any of you serialize classes containing `ImmutableTable` attributes? How could I do this, without resorting to using a `Map` of `Map`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though ImmuttableTable isn't serializable, you could always use a [HashBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) or one of the other [Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) implementations.  And then after deserialization, use ImmutableTable.copyOf(deserialized) to get the ImmutableTable again.  Not exactly elegant, but simple enough to implement.

Comment: That is a very interesting remark. I shall use this instead of `Map<R, Map<C, V>>` in my `readObject` and `writeObject` methods.